# Is there a way to expand a deterministic regular expression in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to know if there is a way to see if part of a regular expression is deterministic or not. For example, the regular expression `0{3}` is deterministic a.k.a there is only one string that matches it: `"000"`. So for example if we had the regular expression `\d0{3}` along with the string `"1"`, is there a way to get the string `"1000"` from that? It seems technically possible since once you have the first digit, you know that the rest of the digits are all 0s and there can only be 3 of them. I don't know if I am missing something or not though.

Comment: https://github.com/fent/randexp.js

Comment: Not sure what input and expected result is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sufficient condition for a regular expression to be deterministic is that it does not contain:

- The `|` operator.
- Any quantifiers (`+`,`*`,`?`,`{n,m}`) other than fixed repetition (`{n}`).
- Any character class matching more than one character (`\w`, `[a-z]`)

These conditions are not *necessary* because of zero-width assertions. For example, the expression `(?!x)(x|y)` only matches `y`. So this simple approach will not cover all cases, though it may suffice for your application.

At least for the case of *true* regular expressions without backreferences, it should be possible to determine whether they are singular. Simply use the standard construction to turn the expression into a nondeterministic finite automaton, then a deterministic finite automaton, then minimize it. The minimal DFA is singular if and only if there is exactly one accepting state, the accepting state has no edges coming from it, and every nonaccepting state has one edge coming from it.

To handle lookahead assertions, you might need to turn the expression into an *alternating* finite automaton, then use an approach similar to Thompson's construction to get the NFA, then proceed from there. Note that the worst-case here could have doubly exponential blowup. You can take `\b` and `^` and similar and translate them to one-character lookbehind assertions, then do some fiddly stuff to get those to work.

Comment: Depending on exactly the requirements you might also want to check that the regex starts with `\A` and end with `\Z` because the regex `0{3}` could match many things including `a000` and `0007`. It might also make sense to check that the case-insensitive flag is not enabled.

Comment: Yeah, it depends on the context and what you consider a “match” to be. If you use a search-like convention where a regex needn't match the entire string, then any regex that doesn't assert this manually can't be singular.